# Conditional check of a column value of a known row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Im new to Pandas.
I have a data frame which has columns user id and gender.
I know the row index.

When I print the gender value for that row,

`print(df_Audience['gender'].iloc[rowindex])`

is printing the gender.

And similarly if I try,

`print(df_Audience['gender'].iloc[rowindex] == 'M')`

is printing true if the gender is male, false otherwise.

But if I try to test,

```
if(df_Audience['gender'].iloc[rowindex] == 'M'):
            print('hello')
```

its throwing an error message saying "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For me the code is running fine and prints hello when true and does not print anything if condition is false. Can you check once again?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is rowIndex is a not a simple integer rather its int64Index. So I have to use

```
 if df_Audience['gender'].iloc[rowindex[0]] == 'M':
                print('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
if df_Audience.loc[rowindex,'gender'] == 'M':
 print("Hello")
```

method 2:

```
if df_Audience.loc[rowindex,:]['gender'] == 'M':
 print("Hello")
```

if rowindex is a list of indices

```
for index in rowindex:
 if df_Audience.loc[index,:]['gender'] == 'M':
  print("Male")
 else:
  print("Female")
```

Comment: My bad.. I have the C++ background, and used to have the parenthesis for if testing. Thanks for that.

Comment: The expression on the left of == is ambiguos, the above error is generated because pandas is trying to compare multiple values with the right hand side of ==, multiple comparisons must be made using |,& operators.

Comment: if df_Audience.loc[rowindex,'gender'] == 'M':
 print("Hello"))   also gives the same error

Comment: My bad I added an extra bracket. Does it fail to work even after removing the extra paranthesis?

Comment: I dont understand multiple values. Im trying to check the value of gender column at the rowindex th row.

Comment: Is rowindex a list or a single  index?

Comment: rowindex is a int64Index. 'rowindex = df_Audience[(df_Audience['user id'] == userid)].index'

Comment: yes it fails even after removing the extra bracket!

Comment: Check the other method it should work, judging by the above comment I am assuming column userid is unique, isn't it?

Comment: The issue seems to be the type of the rowindex. if I use if(df_Audience['gender'].iloc[0] == 'M') its working. But if I use rowindex as subscript instead of 0, it throws the error

Comment: Yes, it works because it uses an integer index of the series df_Audience['gender'] but a more direct method would be query the dataframe using `df_Audience.loc[rowindex,:]['gender']`

Comment: I think that rowindex is not a single value, checkout the new edit.

Comment: Sure Thanks I'l give a try